# Same Header on different slides with beamer and longtable

Tags: beamer, longtable

When using the Longtable package in a LaTeX Beamerdocument, how can I create a table header shown on every slide containing table contents? The following approach seems not to work:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{title}
\begin{longtable}{cc}
a & b \\ \endfirsthead
c & d \\ \endhead
fooooooooooo & Bar\\ 
fooooooooooo & Bar\\ 
...
\end{longtable}
\end{frame}
```

The headerline with "c d" is never shown. This behaviour doesn't seem right.

Comment: While `allowframebreaks` technicly works it is declared as 'evil' in the `beamer` manual. You should always manually decide what and how much is placed on which slide to avoid overfilled slides. So I would recommend to simply use two (or more) `tabular`s on the same number of slides.

Answer (score 2):

use another package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xtab}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,allowframebreaks]{title}
\tablefirsthead{a & b \\}
\tablehead{c & d \\}

\begin{xtabular}{cc}
fooooooooooo & Bar\\ 
fooooooooooo & Bar\\ 
...
\end{xtabular}
\end{frame}
```