# longtable in beamer environment (lacks headers/footers)

Tags: tables, beamer, longtable

In `Beamer`, I wish to use the `longtable` package to break up tables across multiple frames automatically. I am aware of the `xtab` package, which [works fine in `Beamer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22008/same-header-on-different-slides-with-beamer-and-longtable), but I prefer `longtable` as it is the tool that is used internally by the powerful `tabu` package.

`longtable` breaks up tables just fine in `Beamer`, but fails to include headers and footers (with the exception of the first header). Is this a bug in `Beamer`?, `longtable`? Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Here's a short file that demonstrates this issue:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim,longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile] \small %
  In Beamer, the \texttt{longtable} package
  successfully breaks up tables, but fails to
  include headers and footers (except for the
  first header).  Here's the source of this file,
  go to next frame to see how \texttt{longtable}
  fails: \tiny
  \verbatiminput{\jobname.tex}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks] \large          %
  \begin{longtable}{cc}                           %
    FirstHeadA & FirstHeadB \endfirsthead         %
    HeadA & HeadB \endhead                        %
    LastFootA & LastFootB \endlastfoot            %
    FootA & FootB \endfoot                        %
    01A&01B\\02A&02B\\03A&03B\\04A&04B\\05A&05B\\ %
    06A&06B\\07A&07B\\08A&08B\\09A&09B\\10A&10B\\ %
    11A&11B\\12A&12B\\13A&13B\\14A&14B\\15A&15B\\ %
    16A&16B\\17A&17B\\18A&18B\\19A&19B\\20A&20B\\ %
    21A&21B\\22A&22B\\23A&23B\\24A&24B\\25A&25B   %
  \end{longtable}                                 %
\end{frame}                                       %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

EDIT:
The `xtab` package is an extension of the `supertabular` package, which also works fine in `Beamer`.

Answer (score 12):

It's not really a bug if two packages written in different centuries don't quite work together: it's just the way it is. `longtable` relies on a more or less standard output routine to split up the pages and insert headers and footers. Page breaking in `beamer` is far from standard, to implement all the hidden internal pages for `<>` overlays.

It may be possible to make it work automatically but as a presentation is not likely to have tables with hundreds of pages, it is simpler to split the pages manually. Either simply by having two frames, or if you want longtable to ensure the column widths are maintained across the page break, use a breakable frame, but just add the head and foot rows "by hand".

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim,longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile] \small %
  In Beamer, the \texttt{longtable} package
  successfully breaks up tables, but fails to
  include headers and footers (except for the
  first header).  Here's the source of this file,
  go to next frame to see how \texttt{longtable}
  fails:

 \tiny
  \verbatiminput{\jobname.tex}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]         %
  \begin{longtable}{cc}                           %
    FirstHeadA & FirstHeadB\\% \endfirsthead         %
    01A&01B\\02A&02B\\03A&03B\\04A&04B\\05A&05B\\
 %
    06A&06B\\07A&07B\\08A&08B\\09A&09B\\10A&10B\\ %
    11A&11B\\12A&12B\\13A&13B\\14A&14B\\15A&15B\\ %
    FootA & FootB\\%
\newpage
    HeadA & HeadB\\% \endhead                        %
    16A&16B\\17A&17B\\18A&18B\\19A&19B\\20A&20B\\ %
    21A&21B\\22A&22B\\23A&23B\\24A&24B\\25A&25B\\
    LastFootA & LastFootB 
  \end{longtable}                                 %
\end{frame}                                       %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Package `longtable` works by interacting with the output routine and class `beamer` is quite different than "normal" document classes and output routines.

As workaround package `supertabular` can be used:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks] \large
  \tablefirsthead{FirstHeadA & FirstHeadB\\}
  \tablehead{HeadA & HeadB\\}
  \tabletail{FootA & FootB\\}
  \tablelasttail{LastFootA & LastFootB\\}
  \begin{supertabular}{cc}
    01A&01B\\02A&02B\\03A&03B\\04A&04B\\05A&05B\\
    06A&06B\\07A&07B\\08A&08B\\09A&09B\\10A&10B\\
    11A&11B\\12A&12B\\13A&13B\\14A&14B\\15A&15B\\
    16A&16B\\17A&17B\\18A&18B\\19A&19B\\20A&20B\\
    21A&21B\\22A&22B\\23A&23B\\24A&24B\\25A&25B\\
  \end{supertabular}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- In opposite to package `longtable` package `supertabular` uses separate tables for each page. Thus the column widths are not preserved from one to another page.
- Also `supertabular` uses a heuristics to determine, which rows would fit on one page. It is less optimal than `longtable` to fill the page.

Comment: This has the defect that column widths aren't necessarily preserved. If the data have fixed widths as in this example, one has to manually adjust the first/normal headers and the tail to have the same widths.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, also `longtable` fills the page better.

Comment: `supertabular` is superceded by `xtab` (which extends `supertabular` and reduces its weaknesses [according to the author](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbay.uchicago.edu%2Ftex-archive%2Fmacros%2Flatex%2Fcontrib%2Fxtab%2Fxtab.pdf&ei=93LsUf3dLeL4yQGupYCYCg&usg=AFQjCNHAjZvy8qmi_1xRme6gkEntgtUYtQ&bvm=bv.49478099,d.aWc)). I have already already noted that `xtab` (and implicitly `supertabular`) work fine in beamer in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind setting the breaking point yourself, you could use the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Frametitle}
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption={Some caption}
]{
   colspec = {@{}XXXXX@{}}, 
   width = 0.85\linewidth,
   rowhead = 1,
   cells={halign=c},
   row{1}={font=\bfseries}
}
\toprule
Head & Head  & Head & Head & Head \\
\midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\\pagebreak
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]