# How to automatically break a frame into next frame in beamer when the first frame is deem to be full

Tags: beamer, page-breaking

I am building a presentation and neet to define my notation as I have in my MWE but it is too long to stay in a frame and I will not want to manually break its frame. How can I automatically brake the frame of such like table of content has in its option.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\frame[allowframebreaks]{\tableofcontents}
\begin{frame}[shrink=50]
\frametitle{Notation}
\begin{block}{~}
    The following gives a list of notations used in this thesis.
\end{block}
\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Symbol & Meaning \\
    $X_{t}$ & Observed time series \\
    $X^{*}_{t}$ & Bootstrapped time series \\
    $X_{i}$ & Set of random i.i.d. variables \\
    $n$ & Length of time series \\
    $\phi$ & phi \\
    $\Theta$ & Theta \\
    $B$ & Number of bootstrap replicate \\
    $*$ & Star notation indicating a bootstrap replicate \\
    $l$ & Block length \\
    $m$ & Number of block resampled \\
    $k$ & Number of lag \\
    $\mu$ & Mean of population \\
    $\varepsilon_{t}$ & Error term of time series \\
    $ARIMA$ & Autoregressive Integrated Moving average \\
    $ARMA$ & Autoregressive Moving average \\
    $AR$ & Autoregressive \\
    $MA$ & Moving average \\
    $expect$ & Expected value \\
    $\sigma_x^2$ & Sigma squared \\
    $var$ & Variance \\
    i.i.d & Independent identical distribution \\
    $theta_{n}$ & Theta \\
    $\hat\theta_{n}$ & Theta hat \\
    $\sum$ & Summation \\
    $\int$ & Integral \\
    $p$ & Order of Autoregressive model \\
    $q$ & Order of moving average model
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In this code I have to shrink the notation frame to make it seat in a frame which I should not have if I have something like `\frame[allowframebreaks]{\notation}` like it is don for `table of contents`

Comment: Do you really have to add this list in (the beginning of) your presentation? I doubt that such a long list will have any benefit for the audience. Why not simply explain certain symbols during your presentation and only when absolutely needed?

Comment: Thank you, I need it

Comment: In that case, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124945/134144 might be interesting, although I would not recommend to do so.

Comment: don't put the list in a tabular and a table, use a list instead. Then allowframebreaks should work.

Comment: Did Ulrike Fischer's comment help solve your problem ? While it seems to be a good solution, I agree with leandriis that such information will be of little help at the beginning of a presentation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments and the OP didn't answer follow-up questions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Taking it out of the table does not work, if you think it works prove it by showing your MWE

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in the comment: use a list instead of a table and a tabular.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\intstepinline\int_step_inline:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\frame[allowframebreaks]{\tableofcontents}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Notation}
\begin{block}{~}
    The following gives a list of notations used in this thesis.
\end{block}
\begin{description}
\intstepinline{100}{\item[symbol#1] Meaning} % to get many items
\end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this your code works but putting in my symbol and meaning (line 13 to line 40) does not

Comment: Look I will not reformat your code for you. You will have to change the code to add the \item and remove the & and \\ yourself.

Comment: honestly I will appreciate if you edit it for me. Each my attempt to do that is a miss

Comment: Sorry I don't have the time for this.  It is not difficult to write a list entry like `\item[symbol] Meaning` or `\item[$theta_{n}]  Theta `.

Comment: Each my attempt to do that is a miss. I did remove `&` and `\ \`  but to put `\begin{list{label{spacing}`   content...  `\end{list}` is the problem for me

Comment: well my example doesn't use list, but description. If you want some other list, better ask a new question. this is not something for the comments which I'm the only one to see.